# Julia: Write HDF5 in MPI mode for both distributed (MPI) and non-distributed data

Tags: julia, mpi

I'm an experienced user of both HDF5 and MPI and I'm relatively new to Julia.

In other languages, I would open a file sequentially, 1 processor at a time, and append a hyperslab where each proc's data should go in the general field (or just make a file per processor and "join" them later).

I've seen Julia has a mechanism of opening a file using the h5open(..., comm) where the MPI communicator would be given as an argument.
I have played a bit with it and got it all to work just fine, but I have some confusion/uncertainty regarding how this works, in particular when writing "non MPI" fields.

So let's a assume there are 2 vectors (1D array of numbers or whatever) which I want to write to an HDF5 file, one dataset per vector.

`vec_loc` contains a **portion of the data**, so say 2 elements out of 16 total elements, spread over 8 processors.

`vec_glob` is a "global" vector of data and **is the same** in all 8 processors.

if I open a file

```
h5open(filename,"r+",comm) do file
        # Join all parts of vec_glob
        dset = create_dataset(file, "vec_loc", datatype(eltype(vec_loc)), (tuple(nInner); tuple(nGlobal)) )    # in this example nInner=2 and nGLobal=16 (8 processors)
        # Fill data
        dset[GlobalIndex] = vec_loc
end
```

I will get each processor to write the portion of `vec_loc` into the appropriate location (hyperslab?) in the HDF5, so it ends up having all of them ion the correct `GlobalIndex` position.
Obviously Julia knows that the field only needs to be created once, or I would've gotten error that `dset` already exists.

My question is, what is happening with the "non-MPI" vector, that is if I run

```
h5open(filename,"r+",comm) do file
        # vec_glob is the same for all procs
        dset = create_dataset(file, "vec_glob", datatype(eltype(vec_glob)), tuple(length(vec_glob)) )    # vec_glob is the same size and data for all procs.
        # Fill data
        dset[:] = vec_glob
end
```

What is actually happening?

Is the first processor writing the dataset and then every other one is overwriting it (so I have to limit that only one processor writes)?

I know that there is an error when trying to create a dataset that already exists, but obviously using the `comm` part makes Julia understand that this is only done once, so I'm suspecting some sophistication overall.

If they are overwriting existing data, shouldn't there be some error regarding that as I would get in C or Fortran?

If indeed it is overwriting, is there an elegant way to modify it rather than doing something like `if isequal(mp_rank,0) dset=...` separately?